# Permission Denied in VS Code while writing C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, permission-denied

My **c program** are not running in **VS Code**, it is showing that **permission denied**.
When I turn off my real time scanning[ of MacAfee live safe] then it is working for me.

But I have to do that for my every C Program. Is there any permanent solution to it.

And, my rest of the language code are working properly.

[My C Program Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFxgZ.png)

[See the terminal and the my MacAfee notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln5DW.png)

Comment: Post code as code, not image, please.

Comment: You should be able to select windows "Devleoper Mode" in the Settings. See [Enable your device for development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)

Comment: Permanent solution is to uninstall McAfee.

Comment: I got the solution. There is a two solution:
1. First my file name was **bubbleSort.cpp** , but it has to be **.c** means **bubbleSort.c** as I was running C Program.
2. If I **want to run** the code **in .cpp** then I should include `#include<iostream>`

Comment: But thanks for helping me guys

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. There is a two solution:

1. First my file name was `bubbleSort.cpp` , but it has to be `.c` means `bubbleSort.c` as I was running C Program.
2. If I `want to run` the code `in .cpp` then I should include `#include<iostream>` header file.